# XIB File Not Loading Properly In Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I was creating a new View-based Application in XCode, adding some outlet and actions, using the IBAction and IBOutlet tags, into the automatically created controller view header file. I then double clicked the 'project_name_ViewController.xib' to launch the interface builder. 
However the outlets and actions did not appear in interface builder. The only way I could get them to appear was the close the xib file and reopen it through file -> open command in Interface Builder it's self.

I recently upgraded to Snow Leopard, before that I never had this problem.

Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode is full of strange bugs. I always follow my 15 step arcane black magic ritual before I make an ad-hoc or release build. Any time something like your problem happens, I put it down to the flying monkeys twisting bolts somewhere in Xcode and restart the program (sometimes the computer). That generally fixes it.

Of course with outlets and actions, it's easy to forget to save the source header before you swap over. Make sure to save and build. Errors in the source can stop them from showing up in IB too.

Comment: Just to support this answer: save and build, then open XIB.

Comment: X-Code seemed to magically fix it's self, who said computer were deterministic?

Comment: Ha, the view wasn't showing up, so I followed this advice: saved, closed and reopened... viola!  There's my view again!  Thanks.

Comment: i really didnt believe this would fix my problem, i tried everything from clean, analyze, reset content on emulator, even closing and restarting xcode didnt work.  in the end i needed to restart and then everything worked.  stupid xcode